# Different Results Sending Byte Array

Tags: c#, android, arrays, unity-game-engine, encode

Can someone please explain the difference between the 2 examples below:

1. Pre-build, in Unity, dragging a file (that is renamed from test.jpg to test.jpg.bytes) to a slot defined as a TextAsset (imageAsset) and then using this code:

   ```
   private byte[] PrepareImageFile()
   {
       int width = Screen.width;
       int height = Screen.height;
       var tex = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);

       tex.LoadImage(imageAsset.bytes);
       tex.Apply();
       byte[] bytes = tex.EncodeToPNG();
       Destroy(tex);
       return bytes;
   }
   ```
2. Post-build, on an Android tablet, passing in a gallery image path (aPath) then using this code:

   ```
   private byte[] PrepareTheFile(string aPath)
   {
       byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(aPath);
       int width = Screen.width;
       int height = Screen.height;
       var tex = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);

       tex.LoadImage(data);
       tex.Apply();        
       byte[] bytes = tex.EncodeToPNG();        
       Destroy(tex);
       return bytes;
   }
   ```

The reason I know they are different is when the image is sent to a facial recognition API (using bytes), #1 returns accurate results (9/10 identified), but #2 returns inaccurate results (only 1/10 identified correctly).

There are no errors and the image must be reaching its destination for analysis as 1 of the 10 people get identified correctly.

```
public void GrabImage()
    {
        NativeGallery.Permission permission = NativeGallery.GetImageFromGallery((path) =>
        {
            if (path != null)
            {
                texture = new Texture2D(300, 300, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
                texture.LoadImage(File.ReadAllBytes(path));

                Debug.Log(_celebTextAttributes.text + "W:" + texture.width + " x H:" + texture.height);

                texture.Apply();
                _celebTextAttributes.SetText("Path: " + path);
                imagePath = path;
            }
        }, "Select an image from", "image/png");

        _celebImage.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = texture;
    }
```

Any help?

Comment: What's the `gallery image path` path you are passing to second function?

Comment: Thanks for responding - I am using https://github.com/yasirkula/UnityNativeGallery so an example of the path passed is /storage/emulated/0/Downloda/modern-family.jpg

Comment: What's your Unity and Android version?

Comment: Unity: 2018.1.0b9, Android: 6.0.1.

Comment: Ok but how did you generate the `/storage/emulated/0/Downloda/modern-family.jpg` string? Is that hardcoded or did you use a certain function? Just modify your code to add how `PrepareTheFile(string aPath)` is called and how you got the value you passed to it

Comment: I use this GrabImage method (created using the UnityNativeGallery code) to obtain the path and then it is transposed into global variable imagePath for using outside of the method...

Comment: Please add to your question. Hard to read from comment section

Comment: How do you format code in a comment?

Comment: Edit your question and add the code there. You can't format code in the comment section

Comment: Since I am using the same test image that has dimensions 810 x 540, I tested setting the Texture2D to those dimensions, but with the same inaccurate results.

Comment: Your edited code and original code seems very much different. I don't think I can help you because this does not look like the exact code you are using. The only outcome I can see from this is both of us wasting our time to solve a problem that's really somewhere else. Although I hope you get a solution but please make sure that the code in your question is the actual code you are using

Comment: I'm not sure what was different, I pasted the code that I am using and that I'm having issues with, but I appreciate you offering to help initially and I'm sorry you feel that assisting any further would be wasting anyones time.  Thank you.

Comment: Android 6.0.1 requires run-time permission, did you ask for permission before accessing th Gallery?

Comment: Thanks for responding, I believe that is handled by the NativeGallery.Permission command in the GrabImage method.  The required image is displayed on a texture with no problems, so I'm not sure if it's a permission issue.

Comment: No. You have to ask for permission. Log permission to see the output. `Debug.Log(permission)`. If the output is not Granted then that's a permission issue.

Comment: I added the Debug.Log statement at the end of the GrabImage method and it says "Granted".

Comment: Then that's not the issue. Have you set Write Permission to External (SDCard) in Player Settings?

Comment: Yes it was set to that.